# How do I update a subscription rule using namespacemanager

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have an existing subscription and would like to update the rule filter for the subscription via the NamespaceManager.

I see where I can get a list of rules, but I don't see how to update them.  I've noticed that in the ServiceBus explorer, I have the option to modify/add rules, so I'm assuming its exposed somewhere in the API.

Answer (score -1):

Found it!

You can get a list of rules associated with a subscription via the namespace manager, 
but you need to create an instance of the subscription client for that topic and subscription if you want to be able to add/remove rules.

I was able to figure this out by looking at the ServiceBus Explorer code.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Would be useful if you had added the actual class name or some sample code